# Problems while Publishing WebSite in ASP.NET Showing Error of Old Code

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment

I have encountered a problem when I was trying to Publish my ASP.NET website.. I deleted all my published websites in **"C://inetpub/wwwroot"** and also delete in IIS Manager. After some time I was working with my code and changed my code. And now when I try to run my website it is still my old code. Whatever changes I made to the code is not reflecting. What is the problem?

Comment: Could you clarify please. You have published your website and you don't see the latest code being deployed? Couple of things

1) Have you got anything in GAC
2) Is your IIS website pointing to the right directory?

Comment: I tried to publish my WebSite but it was not successful.. After that I made changes to my code and I tried to run it(not deploying), it is still showing my previous error msgs..

Comment: So the issue is that your publish didn't get through. You would have errors shown in the output window. Share an errors if you see any.

If you are debugging code, see if you are bound to the website our using IIS Express. If it is later, your publishing hasn't got anything to do with it. if you are bound to the published website, please publish again.

Comment: whatever I do, my new code is not reflecting in my chrome browser, but it is displaying in IE.. Only thing i can do to make it work is by changing the filename again and again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used manifest file to cache my forms.. Due to this manifest only, it is showing my old code... now modified my manifest file to cache my newly modified code.. Thanks everyone...

Comment: How did you go about doing this?  I just ran into this problem again and IIS is running an old version (asp.net - my mvc sites work just fine - go figure).

Answer (score 0):

Your publish etc. did not go through successfully.

Ensure that your new code is compiled cleanly and **re-published successfully** to the web server. (select the option to delete existing files)

Comment: I did that as well.. This time I am not publishing, I m just running my code.. but its still returning my previous errors.. My modified code is not reflecting...

Comment: This is a known bug in IIS. If, after rebooting the server (the entire machine), it still persists, you need to find out exactly where the old dll is cached on the server and delete it. Best not to use Publish - when it works, it works great, when it doesn't, you'll spend days playing the IIS guessing game.